# Find a limit using Chevyshev's inequality

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X$ a random variable with a distribution function $F(x)$, use the Chevyshev's Inequality to show: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(1-F(x)) = 0$$

Unfortunately I'm deeply lost figuring out this one, because I don't have a begining point clear. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If $x>\mu$,
$$P(X\geq x) = P((X-\mu)\geq x -\mu)\leq P(|X-\mu|\geq x-\mu)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{(x-\mu)^2}$$ or 
$$1-F_X(x)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{(x-\mu)^2}$$
This can be a starting point for the proof.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned about existence of mean, let alone the variance. You are asked to prove the result for **any**  distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Let $F(x)=0$ for $x <1$ and $1-\frac 1 x$ for $x \geq 1$. Then $x(1-F(x)) \to 1$.

However, if $EX<\infty$ then $EXI_{X>x} \geq x P(X>x)=x(1-F(x))$ so $x(1-F(x)) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Try to apply Chebyshev's inequality to your distribution.